# Jenkins with Github Plugin build for EACH push

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have Jenkins 1.629 with the Github Plugin configured to build for each push to my repository.

I have noticed that when I push multiple times during jenkins' quiet period (e.g. before the first jenkins job has begun but after it has been queued), that jenkins will simply build all of those commits as one build instead of building them separately.

How do I get jenkins to build each trigger separately? Is there any way using a parameterized build that I can achieve this?

Comment: The quiet period is configurable in the Configuration. Remove the value and the build will start automatically without waiting.

Comment: That is assuming there are executors available to build. If the executors ever get filled up, then the problem I described will begin occurring. Whereby the very next build that starts will actually check out the HEAD revision which contains all the ensuing pushes.